# Yaml YQ - How do you use [], but still print out the keys that the iterator refers to

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml file that looks like this:

```
---
component1:
  tests:
    - name: test1
      type: manual
    - name: test2
      type: automated
    - name: test3
      type: manual
    - name: test4
      type: automated
    - name: test5
      type: manual
    - name: test6
      type: automated
component2:
  tests:
    - name: test1
      type: manual
    - name: test2
      type: automated
    - name: test3
      type: manual
    - name: test4
      type: automated
    - name: test5
      type: manual
    - name: test6
      type: automated
```

I am trying to list only the automated tests, but keep the information about which component the tests are in.

I would like the output to be similar to this:

```
component1:
  tests:
    - name: test2
      type: automated
    - name: test4
      type: automated
    - name: test6
      type: automated
component2:
  tests:
    - name: test2
      type: automated
    - name: test4
      type: automated
    - name: test6
      type: automated
```

But I would also take any answer that allowed me to group the automated tests by component.

I have tried `yq e '.[].tests | map(select(.type == "automated"))' file.yaml -P`, but that just gives me the following output and the component information is lost and I just get the following output:

```
- name: test2
  type: automated
- name: test4
  type: automated
- name: test6
  type: automated
- name: test2
  type: automated
- name: test4
  type: automated
- name: test6
  type: automated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can use the update select operator with `|=` to update the results back to the `tests` list

```
yq e '.[].tests |= map(select(.type == "automated"))' file.yaml -P
```

Note that, if you are using `yq` version [above 4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), the eval action `e` is the default one and can be skipped altogether.